# How to write an algorithm to check if a list of coordinates are 'chained'?

Tags: python

From an input of coordinates of dots (which form tetris like blocks) in a list(unsorted) I have to figure out if they're all chained/linked together. In other words all the dots/coordinates have to touch either horizontally or vertically(not diagonal) for it to return True.

I have no idea how to try solving this problem, I thought maybe by seeing if every block touches at least 1 other block, but then I figured that it'll give true when i have 2 separate blocks of 2 dots each for example so that's not a solution.

[(2, 0), (1, 0), (0, 0), (0, -1), (0, -2)] is an example of a block which has to return true.

[(0,-1),(0,0),(0,2),(0,3)] should return False.

Comment: Look at the flood-fill algorithm

Comment: (a) What does “touches” mean? Does a block touch another block if an only if its reference point (e.g., (2, 3)) is exactly 1 unit away from another block’s reference point in a vertical or horizontal direction? (b) Do you only need to check if blocks are chained in the order listed (the first is touching the second, the second is touching the third, the third is touch the fourth, and so on), or could they be out of order? (c) If they could be out of order, do blocks count as chained if they fork, forming a Y-linkage where they are all connected but not in one linear chain?

Comment: @EricPostpischil a) Yes it has to be 1 unit away in horizontal or vertical direction, diagonal doesn't count as touching b) it doesn't matter which block 'touches' which it's just to check if the input 'block' is one whole, meaning that every block touches at least one other and without there being separate pieces. So this answers c) as well

Answer (score 0):

A simple (not efficient) algorithm for this is:

1. Start with a list L of points to be checked.
2. If L is empty, return true/false/error, as you please.
3. Remove the first point from L and initialize a new list C to contain it. (C will be a list of checked points that are all connected to each other through a chain of intermediate points in C.)
4. For each point x in L:

   1. For each point y in C:

      1. If x touches y, remove x from L, add x to C, and go to 4 (starting over in L).
5. At this point, the loop has finished without restarting. If L is empty, the points are all in C and hence form a connected chain. If L is not empty, they do not.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an efficient algorithm. Its time complexity is O(n*log*n) and its space complexity is O(n), where n is the number dots.

I will illustrate the algorithm with the following example where o's represent dots in the x-y plane.

```
8| o o o     
7| o o o o o 
6| o   o   o 
5|     o   o
4| o   o o o
3| o   o o
2| o o o o o o
y ------------
 x 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

1. Sort the list of n dots by increasing values of their x, and then y coordinates. For our example, we have:

   ```
   [(2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 6), (2, 7), (2, 8), (3, 2), (3, 7), (3, 8), ...    (6, 2), (6, 4), (6, 5), (6, 7), (7, 2)]
   ```
2. For every series of dots that have the same x value, build an array of nodes, where each node represents the connected dots along the y axis. In our example, for x = 2, we create node N0 for the dots that go from y = 2 to 4, and node N1 for dots that go from y = 6 to 8. We denote these nodes N0:[2 4], and N1:[6 8], and the array containing them is denoted A0:2 (where 2 is their x value). Doing this for all x values yields:

   ```
   A0:2 = [N0:[2 4], N1:[6 8]]
   A1:3 = [N2:[2 2], N3:[7 8]]
   A2:4 = [N4:[4 8]]
   A3:5 = [N5:[2 4], N6:[7 7]]
   A4:6 = [N7:[2 2], N8:[4 7]]
   A5:7 = [N9:[2 2]]
   ```
3. For each pair of arrays Ai and Ai+1, we compare the y intervals of nodes between Ai and Ai+1, and if they intersect, we connect their nodes with an edge. In our example, we get the following graph. Note that a node can have at most 4 edges. Note also that because nodes of the two arrays are sorted by increasing y values, the time to find intersections is proportional to the number of nodes in the arrays.

   ```
   N1-N3    N6
        \  /  \
         N4    N8
        /  \  /
   N0-N2    N5-N7-N9
   ```
4. Choose any node in the graph. Delete the node and all the nodes connected to it. This can be done recursively or iteratively. If the resulting graph is empty, all nodes are connected and a solution exists. Otherwise, there is no solution.

Because a node can have at most 4 edges, the space complexity is O(n).

Step 1 is O(n*log*n), and steps 2, 3, and 4 are O(n). Overall time complexity: O(n*log*n).

Comment: Once the elements are sorted, a graph can be constructed in O(n) time, and then any component traversal can determine connectedness. So step 2 does not affect the complexity; step 3 could be replaced by a graph construction on the individual dots. Incidentally, I think “Note that a node can have at most 4 edges” is incorrect; a vertical (constant x) line of 2n−1 consecutive dots can have n neighbors on each side. However, it is of no consequence to the complexity analysis.

Answer (score -1):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors 
board = [['B', 'R', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'R', 'R', 'B', 'B'],
         ['R', 'B', 'R', 'B', 'B', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'R'],
         ['B', 'R', 'B', 'B', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
         ['B', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'R', 'B', 'R'],
         ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'R', 'B', 'R', 'R', 'B', 'R'],
         ['B', 'R', 'B', 'R', 'R', 'B', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'B'],
         ['B', 'B', 'R', 'B', 'R', 'B', 'R', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
         ['R', 'B', 'R', 'B', 'R', 'B', 'R', 'R', 'B', 'R'],
         ['B', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'B', 'B', 'R', 'B'],
         ['R', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'B', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'B'],
         ['B', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'R', 'B', 'R'],
         ['R', 'R', 'B', 'R', 'R', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'R', 'B'],
         ['R', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
         ['B', 'R', 'B', 'B', 'R', 'B', 'R', 'B', 'B', 'R'],
         ['R', 'B', 'R', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'B'],
         ['R', 'B', 'R', 'B', 'R', 'B', 'R', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
         ['B', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'B', 'R', 'B', 'R', 'R', 'R'],
         ['R', 'R', 'B', 'R', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'R', 'R'],
         ['B', 'B', 'R', 'B', 'B', 'R', 'B', 'R', 'B', 'B'],
         ['B', 'B', 'B', 'R', 'R', 'B', 'B', 'R', 'B', 'B']]

def maper(board):
  s = str()
  for row_index, _row in enumerate(board):
    for col_index ,cell in enumerate(_row):
      r = f'{row_index}'
      c = f'{col_index}'
      if row_index < 10  :
        r = f'{row_index} '
      if col_index < 10  :
    c = f' {col_index}'
      
      s += f'{cell}({r},{c})'
    print(s)
    s = ""

def recognition(board):
  blocks = list()
  taked_cells = list()
  for r in range(20):
    for c in range(10):
      if [r,c] not in taked_cells :
        block = list()
        block.append([r,c])
        taked_cells.append([r,c])
        analyzer = True
        while analyzer is True:
          analyzer = False
          for cor in block :
            x = cor[0]
            y = cor[1]
            if ([x+1,y] not in block) and (x+1 < 20): 
          if (board[x][y] == board[x+1][y]):
            block.append([x+1,y])
            taked_cells.append([x+1,y])
            analyzer = True
            if ([x,y+1] not in block) and (y+1 < 10): 
          if (board[x][y] == board[x][y+1]):
            block.append([x,y+1])
            taked_cells.append([x,y+1])
            analyzer = True
            if ([x,y-1] not in block) and (y-1 >= 0):    
          if board[x][y] == board[x][y-1]:
            block.append([x,y-1])
            taked_cells.append([x,y-1])
            analyzer = True
            if ([x-1,y] not in block) and (x-1 >= 0): 
          if (board[x][y] == board[x-1][y]):
            block.append([x-1,y])
            taked_cells.append([x-1,y])
            analyzer = True
          if analyzer is False:
        blocks.append(block)

  
  #length = (map(len, blocks))
  #print(sorted(length))
  #np_blocks = np.array([xi+[None]*(length-len(xi)) for xi in blocks])
  #print(np_blocks)
  #npblock = np.array(blocks,dtype=object)
  data = [ [0 if b == 'B' else 1 for b in bor ] for bor in board]
  cmap = colors.ListedColormap(['green','red'])
  plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
  plt.pcolor(data[::-1],cmap=cmap,edgecolors='k', linewidths=2)
  plt.show()
  
  for bloc in blocks:
    s=str()
    for b in bloc :
      s += board[b[0]][b[1]]
    print(s)


#maper(board)
recognition(board)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: 1 downvote, please explain your code, add documentations, or supportijg link if any.